# Scala Play 2.5.0 2.5.1 Filtering with access to result body

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.5

I didn't find a way to get the body within a Filter in Play 2.5.x.
I want to create a "BadRequestLogFilter", which should log the request AND the result, if my appliation returns a status code 400-500

In Play 2.4.x, I used Iteratees and it worked.
I was not able to migrate this piece of code to Play 2.5.x. Can somebody give me a hint here? Maybe the hole approach to get the body in an Filter is an bad idea?

Here is my old (in 2.4.x working properly) Filter for Play 2.4.x

```
class BadRequestLogFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
  val logger = Logger("bad_status").underlyingLogger

  override def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val resultFuture = next(request)
    resultFuture.foreach(result => {

      val status = result.header.status
      if (status < 200 || status >= 400) {
        val c = Try(request.tags(Router.Tags.RouteController))
        val a = Try(request.tags(Router.Tags.RouteActionMethod))

        val body = result.body.run(Iteratee.fold(Array.empty[Byte]) { (memo, nextChunk) => memo ++ nextChunk })
        val futResponse = body.map(bytes => new String(bytes))
        futResponse.map { response =>

          val m = Map("method" -> request.method,
            "uri" -> request.uri,
            "status" -> status,
            "response" -> response,
            "request" -> request,
            "controller" -> c.getOrElse("empty"),
            "actionMethod" -> a.getOrElse("empty"))

          val msg = m.map { case (k, v) => s"$k=$v" }.mkString(", ")
          logger.info(appendEntries(m), msg)
        }
      }
    })
    resultFuture
  }
}
```

I guess I just need an valid replacement for this line here:

```
val body = result.body.run(Iteratee.fold(Array.empty[Byte]) { (memo, nextChunk) => memo ++ nextChunk })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of a result in Play 2.5.x is of type [HttpEntity](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.http.HttpEntity)

So once you have the result you can get the body and then materialize it:

```
val body = result.body.consumeData(mat)
```

Here `mat` is the `implicit Materializer` you have. This is going to return you a `Future[ByteString]` which you can then decode to get a String representation (I have omitted future handling here for simplicity):

```
val bodyAsString = body.decodeString("UTF-8")
logger.info(bodyAsString)
```